# Spring Autowiring in Inherited Classes

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Suppose I have a class A:

```
public class A {
    @Autowire embeddedKafka;
}
```

Suppose the following class extends A:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class B extends A {

}
```

Now when the object for class B is created, class A's constructor will be called. I am wondering if the `embeddedKafka` instance will be `autowired`? 
In my test, this is what I am observing. My question is this: when there is no instance of `A` getting created, why does Spring autowire the `embeddedKafka` instance?

Edit:

Comment: Your last paragraph starts with "when the object for class B is created". And it ends with "when there is no instance of B getting created". Those are contradictory. What exactly is your question? If something is autowired into an instance of B, then there is an instance of B.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry was a mistake. I mean, when there is no instance of A getting created.

Comment: B extends A. So an instance of B **is** an instance of A. So an instance of A **is** being created. Just as you told it yourself: class A's constructor will be called. If a class constructor is being called, then an instance of that class is being constructed, by definition.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for responding, but is it so? What I read is whereas the superclass' constructor is called, it does not mean its object is created. Getting a bit confused.

geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-52-java-object-creation-of-inherited-classes/

Comment: It works just like in the real world: A Banana is a Fruit. If you create a Banana, you create a Fruit. You don't create two objects, just one. And this object is a Banana. And it's also a Fruit.

Comment: So it's like spring creates a bean of the test class, and since it needs an embeddedKafka instance, it autowires it. Think that answers it. Could you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The article you linked to uses poor terminology, and is also plain incorrect by using the fact that two identical hashCodes mean a single object.

Comment: Yes, that was a poor reference. Just that I pasted the first link that appeared (I was pretty sure that only a single instance is created, that you later clarified). Embarrassing mistake, lesson learnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B extends A. So an instance of B is an instance of A. So when an instance of B is being created, an instance of A is being created (just like, when you make a baby girl, you also make a baby human, because a girl is a human). You told it yourself: class A's constructor will be called.

If a class constructor is being called, then an instance of that class is being constructed, by definition.